# How to run two functions in parallel in python when one collects data from the other?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I'm new to multiprocessing and want to collect data in one function and write data in another function simultaneously. Here's a psuedocode of what I have.

```
def Read_Data():
 for num in range(0,5):

     ## Read 5  random values

     print('Reading ' + str(values[num]))
 return(values)

def Write_data(values):

 ## Arrange the random values in ascending order

 for num in range(0,5):
     print('Writing' + str(arranged_values[num]))

if __name__=='__main__'
  values = Read_Data()
  Write_data(values)
```

I want the output to look like this.

```
reading 1, writing none
reading 3, writing none
reading 5, writing none
reading 4, writing none
reading 2, writing none
reading 7, writing 1
reading 8, writing 2
reading 10, writing 3
reading 9, writing 4
reading 6, writing 5
```

Now the reason I want it to run parallel is to make sure I'm collecting data all the time and not losing data while I'm modifying and printing.

How can I do it using multiprocessing?

Comment: Sorry Typo. I corrected it

Comment: [use a queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) to pass objects between threads/processes

Comment: I did. But i think I'm not using it right. I didn't really understand the documentation so well. This is what I changed.
Instead of return i changed it to q.put(values).
And then, 
p1 = Process(target = Read_Data, args=(q,))
p1.start()
p2 = Process(target = Write_Data, args=(q.get()))
p2.start()

Comment: Leaving multiprocessing/-threading aside you could turn `read_data` into a generator yielding the single values and then do something like `for value in read_data(): write_data(value)`.

Comment: @ a_guest I didn't get you. How would you achieve it reading only one value? Don't you need atleast two values to compare and arrange them? Would you be willing to share a pseudocode of that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should illustrate a few concepts. The queue is used to pass objects between the processes.

The reader simply gets its value somewhere and places it on the queue.

The writer listens on the queue forever.
Adding a "TERMINATED" signal is a very simple way of telling the writer to stop listening forever (there are other more effective ways using signals and events but this just illustrates the concept).

At the end we "join" on the two processes to make sure they exit before we exit the main process (otherwise they are left hanging in space and time)

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep

def reader(q):
    for i in range(10):
        print("Reading", i)
        q.put(i)
        sleep(1)
    print("Reading TERMINATED")
    q.put("TERMINATE")


def writer(q):
    while True:
        i = q.get()
        if i == "TERMINATE":
            print("Writer TERMINATED")
            break
        print("Writing", i)

q = Queue()

pr = Process(target=reader, args=(q,))

pw = Process(target=writer, args=(q,))

pw.start()

pr.start()

pw.join()
pr.join()
```

Comment: @Will """At the end we "join" on the two processes to make sure they exit before we exit the main process (otherwise they are left hanging in space and time)""". Thank you so much for clearing that up. All this while I assumed that join just ends the 2 processes together. I never realized it ensures process termination before main

Comment: The main process joins on the child processes. When the join stops blocking (meaning the child has exited) then the main can happily end.